# Dlink DIR-615 suddenly stops working - Orange internet light

Tags: networking, router, troubleshooting

I unplugged my Dlink DIR-615 router last night from the wall due to a storm rolling in. I've done this countless times, no problem.

However, when I went to plug it in and use the internet today, nothing. Check everything, cycled everything. Hard reset the router, nothing.

The little globe on the front is red/orange, and it should be green. Windows gives me an error of a "DNS Issue", and the internet works when connected directly to the modem.

How can I fix this issue? Why would it suddenly stop working?

Comment: BTW, the globe icon represents "connection to WAN", in this case your modem.

Comment: Merged, so there might be some info missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, routers can and do die, fortunately, if we're lucky it may be possible to revive them.

Assuming you have checked the cabling to make sure nothing has changed or become loose and you've also tried a hard reset by holding the reset button in for at least 20 seconds and nothing changes, you may have a more severe problem, if so you can try the folowing:

1. Go to http://tinyurl.com/dir615firmware and download the latest firmware (you can also get this from the DLink ftp servers ftp://ftp.dlink.co.uk/)
2. Connect the router directly to the PC and disconnect and other cables.
3. Perform a Crash reset:

Power OFF the device. Press and hold the 'reset' button; while doing so, power on the device again and keep holding the 'reset' button for another 10 seconds. Then release the button and wait until device restarts.

4.log on to the web interface (I believe that's 192.168.0.1 on DLink) and re-flash the firmware. (use IE not another browser)

There are no guarantees this will work and is probably best done once you've tried everything else.

Good luck

Comment: thank you for the great response! I actually figure it out. After doing everything you said, new firmware, etc... I had to clone my MAC address, and viola! it worked!

Comment: Great stuff, really glad you got it working again :)

Comment: That would be  192.168.0.1 not  192.169.0.1. If you're curious, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_ip_address#Private_IPv4_address_spaces for a tad more info

Comment: can you clarify why you only recommend IE to run this? I've never had issues using Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

> I can get to the web interface, but no internet connection – this is all over a LAN connection.

You haven't said anything about why you suspect the router and not your cable/DSL (??) modem. (I'm guessing that you use one or the other).

Since  you have been able to complete a number of firmware changes to your router it sounds like it is working fine. Consider what I think you are implying. The firmware seems to work fine in the router. So there would have to be a failure to the hardware for the WAN ethernet support which would **not** be reported in the router's log. While anything is possible, the router would not be the first device I would suspect.

First thing I would do is to reboot the cable modem. Wait an appropriate period of time and then try reaching the Internet again.

Since you can reach the router's admin page, see what it says about the status of the external WAN/Internet connection. Was the router assigned an (exteral) IP?

Also look at the router's log. If the router has filters for the log, set them to tell you everything. Then reboot the router and check the log again to see what happened when the router booted and attempted to get an IP address from your ISP.

You should also check to see if you are reaching the Internet but unable to view any web pages because you are have DNS problems. Try pinging from your router (should be available under "Tools") one of the [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) servers, `208.67.222.222` or `208.67.220.220`. If this works, but you can't open a web page I would suspect a problem getting results back from your ISP's Domain Name Servers.

One final thing you might try to test out the router vs the modem is to power off the modem for a few (3 to 5??) minutes, connect a PC directly to the modem, then power it up. See if you can reach the Internet then.

Two notes on the above suggestion:

1. I suggest you do **NOT** leave things this way for very long even if it works. Having a PC connected directly to the Internet is an open invitation to others to try to hack into your system.
2. The reason I suggest leaving your modem powered off for a few minutes is because commonly an ISP will note the MAC address of the router or PC which is connected via the  modem. The ISP will refuse to (immediately) assign an IP address to a system with a different MAC address. Typically if you wait a bit the lock-out times out and then any MAC address is allowed.

Comment: OpenDNS is 208.67.220.220 not 222.220

Comment: Oooooops! Thanks. I updated my answer ... and my router. (How embaressing!)

Answer (score 0):

You may just have a burnt out router. My DIR-655 had been getting slower and slower lately and as soon as I swapped it out for a different router my network/internet speeds increased noticably.

Comment: hmm, anything in particular that would cause this??? It's a very well ventilated basement.

Comment: Not that I can think of. I think the consumer-grade routers just aren't meant to last for years and years, particularly if you're using them hard (ie, 24x7 bittorrent). I've gone through three routers in the last ten years this way. They just seem to go bad over time. Or at least, that's my experience..  (with a BEFSR41, WRT54G, DIR-655..)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and what I did was go through the automatic wizard setup.

Go to the modem's IP (192.168.0.1 by default) and run the wizard; it will clone the MAC address of the modem.

For me, it cured the orange light being on all the time.

Comment: Go to the modem's I.P. (http://192.168.0.1/) and run the automatic Wizard which will clone the MAC Address.